# C. how to add header file to my program (using #include)

Tags: c, include, header-files

I have a question about adding a header file to my code file which is called ex6.c . When IM trying to add a header file which is called ex6.h,  to my code like that:

```
#include "ex6.h"
```

I get this error:  cannot open source file "ex6.h"
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the header file (presumably named "ex6.h") located?

Comment: hmm.... have you created the file? If so... where is it located? How do you compile your code?

Comment: The file is in the same folder as the ex6.c file. I wasnt sure where to locate it. Where should I locate it? I used Visual Studio to compile my code